# In Grails, disable name hashing but keep expires header for hashandchange resources plugin?

Tags: caching, grails, requirejs, expires-header

I am using **grails resources plugin**. On client I am using **require.js** to fetch js.

my require.js config -

```
baseUrl: '/js/lib',
```

With resources plugin enabled -

1. browser would make request for **/js/lib/abc.js** wasting ~300ms
2. On reaching server it will be redirected to /static/2432yi4h32kh4232h4k2h34ll.js
3. Browser will find this file in its cache and serve it.

So I disabled **cached-resources** plugin using -

```
grails.resources.mappers.hashandcache.excludes = ['**/*.js']
```

and new require.js config -

```
baseUrl: '/static/js/lib',    
urlArgs: "bust=" + application_version,
```

Removing **cached-resources** solved redirect issue but also removed the expires header which was being set for js files causing browsers to not cache js files at all.

How can I only disable the name hashing in cached-resources and keep the expires headers it sets.
Otherwise, are there any plugins for Grails I can use to set these headers and they work well with Resources plugin.

I am using **Tomcat** and **Haproxy** to serve content.

Comment: I know that cached-resources use cache-headers plugin internally to set expires headers. Is it possible to only explicitly enable this plugin for js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best solution is to put the hashed js file name in require definition, not the original clear name.

You can echo the hashed name using the resource external tag

```
<r:external uri="js/custom.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var urlOfCSSToLoadInJSCode = '${r.external(uri:"css/custom.css").encodeAsJavaScript()}';
</script>
<r:external uri="icons/favicon.ico"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer i was looking for, though I ended up setting a nginx server to serve my static content removing resources plugin completely. Thanks, anyways.